# How to calculate sum of confusion matrix in the case of stratified k- Fold

Tags: r, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I am new to machine learning.  I have applied stratified k-fold on my dataset. How would I get sum of confusion matrix.

Below is my code

```
library(MASS)

cv_lda <- lapply(folds, function(x) { # start of function
  # in the next two lines we will separate the Training set into it's 10 pieces
  training_fold = ForwardPlayers[-x, ] # training fold =  training set minus (-) it's sub test fold
  test_fold = ForwardPlayers[x, ] # here we describe the test fold individually
  # now apply (train) the classifer on the training_fold
  classifier = lda(Rating ~ .,training_fold)
  # next step in the loop, we calculate the predictions and cm and we equate the accuracy
  # note we are training on training_fold and testing its accuracy on the test_fold
  y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = test_fold[-1]) 

  cm = table(test_fold$Rating, y_pred$class)
  #accuracy <- sum(diag(cm))/sum(cm)

  return(cm)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

> addmargins()

-> Or any margin sub-argument

as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

if you meant sum of the totall data in your matrix to measure P+N for accuracy metric, you might try this:
sum(sum(confusion_matrix))

Comment: Please include extra details to the answer, and try to always include code into 'code sample' blocks.